# create an observer for customer logged in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How to create an `observer` for **customer logged in** in Magento?

```
<events>
         <customer_login> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
           <observers>
             <Vi_Cartproduct> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
               <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
               <class>cartproduct/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
               <method>removeProduct</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
               <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
             </Vi_Cartproduct>
           </observers>
         </customer_login>
   </events>
```

The above event not working

Comment: Can you explain your requirements in more details, Means which pages you want to customize ?

Comment: @Amit i am updates the question

Answer (score 2):

Try out this one....

```
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <vi_cartproduct_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Vi_Cartproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>removeProduct</method>
            </vi_cartproduct_model_observer>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
</events>
```

Comment: 1. Have you activated your module ? 2. Show me your observer class code. 3. I have modify the above code check again. Lets know what happen ?

Comment: <?php
class Vi_Cartempty_Model_Observer
{
                       public function removeProduct($event)
                       {
                               
                           foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')>getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
                                   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
                               }
              }
 }

Comment: It seems that you mention the wrong class name here it's Vi_Cartempty_Model_Observer and in config it's Vi_Cartproduct_Model_Observer

Comment: class Vi_Cartproduct_Model_Observer
{

                       public function removeProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
                       {
                               
                               
                           foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')>getQuote()>getItemsCollection() as $item ){
                                   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')>removeItem( $item>getId() )->save();
                               }
                       }
               
}

Comment: Now you need to debug, SO clear the cache, and start debug(like file name etc.) because there is no issue in the code. Just make sure that you have put the above xml code under <frontend> or <global> tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize only the theme you have the `<customer_logged_in>` and `<customer_logged_out>` handles in layout where you can add or remove any block.